# Combining tables in mySQL to keep nulls

Tags: mysql

I have two tables below. I am looking to find all the combinations of `store` and `newid` in `sales2` which are not present in `sales1` and combine them with `sales1`.

I am looking for the end result to be:

```
store  newid  amount  total
 123 |  123  | 12.3 |  1
 456 |  123  | 45.6 |  2
 789 |  adsf | 78.9 |  3
 321 |  123f | NULL | NULL 
 789 |  1654 | NULL | NULL
```

Original Tables

```
CREATE TABLE sales1 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
store  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
newid VARCHAR(30),
amount DOUBLE,
total INT
);

CREATE TABLE sales2 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
store  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
newid VARCHAR(30),
amount DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO sales1 (store, newid, amount, total) VALUES
    ('123','123', 12.3, 1),('456','123', 45.6, 2),('789','adsf', 78.9, 3);

INSERT INTO sales2 (store, newid, amount) VALUES 
    ('123','123', Null),('456','123', Null),('321','123f', Null),('789','1654', Null);
```

Comment: Can you have stores that are in sales1, but not in sales2?

Comment: why have you got two "sales" tables in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can use two different `SELECT` queries for this. First query will fetch all the rows from `sales1` table.
- Second would fetch the remaining rows from `sales2` table, which do not exist in the `sales1` table. We will use `LEFT JOIN` from `sales2` to `sales1` and consider only those rows where `sales1.id` is `NULL` after the Join.
- We will eventually use `UNION ALL` to combine the result-set from both the queries.

---

**Query**

```
SELECT
 s1.store, s1.newid, s1.amount, s1.total 
FROM sales1 s1

UNION ALL 

SELECT
 s2.store, s2.newid, s2.amount, NULL AS total  
FROM sales2 s2
LEFT JOIN sales1 s1
 ON s2.store = s1.store AND 
    s2.newid = s1.newid 
WHERE s1.id IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| store | newid | amount | total |
| ----- | ----- | ------ | ----- |
| 123   | 123   | 12.3   | 1     |
| 456   | 123   | 45.6   | 2     |
| 789   | adsf  | 78.9   | 3     |
| 321   | 123f  |        |       |
| 789   | 1654  |        |       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qTR7Xv33mag7TSzhYSTqYJ/0)

Comment: full outer joins for mysql have already been covered in quite a few questions here on SO. If you think that this is what this question is about, then voting to close would be the right action to take.

Comment: @Shadow it is "like" not specifically Full Join. For eg: take this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql Answers there are combination of left and right join. while here it is not. It just looks like that.

Comment: @Shadow I have removed the line causing doubts.

Comment: This is full outer join, no matter whether you remove that sentence from your answer or not. Flipping around the order of the tables or using left + right joins does not make any difference at all.

Comment: @Shadow I have turned my answer as community answer. You have the power to close it as duplicate, I believe !